# AutoComplete TextBox in C# using User Control not display updated results until form restart

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have windows form and I used user control for another form, my problem is it wont display the results of  the new data in the textbox when Im trying to add new data in sql database until form close. I tried using this.refresh, panel.Update, panel.refresh or even groupbox.refresh since i put groupbox inside the user control.

Here is my code in using autocomplete in textbox:

```
// inside use control_load

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT OwnerName FROM TaxDecRecord", sqlCon);
sqlCon.Open();
SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
AutoCompleteStringCollection mycollection1 = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

while (dr1.Read())
{
    mycollection1.Add(dr1.GetString(0));
}

txtOwnerName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycollection1;
sqlCon.Close();
```

Thank you! your help is highly appreciated

Comment: If you do this only in Form_Load it's clear that you have to re-load the form to update AutoCompleteCustomSource.

Comment: I mean this code is inside the user Control

Comment: But you wrote "//in form load". Please make the context more clear.

Comment: sorry for misleading @KlausGütter I edited it now

Comment: How does your application know you added something to your SQL database? Is this code running on some sort of a timer?

Comment: Im using SqlCommand in an Addbutton to add data in SqlDatabase @CoolBots

Comment: Ok, but does the `AutoCompleteStringCollection` refresh at that time? `Load` events only run once

Comment: How to do it @CoolBots I dont know exactly what you mean, and this is my first program and I dont know much yet. thank you!

Comment: Is there another way to reload user Control with a button? Just like clicking the user control for the first time @CoolBots

Comment: or how to autocomplete a value from datagridview value since my datagridview is in updated data,

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code - except that *it only runs once*, when the form (or the custom control, in your case) is loaded. That's why you're only seeing changes upon application restart.

Since you already have a function that adds new strings to the database, you can update the `AutoCompleteStringCollection` for your `TextBox` at the same time. Suppose that function takes in the new string in a variable called `addMe`, you can then add a line of code, like this:

```cs
txtOwnerName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(addMe);
```

This will update the collection *at the time you're updating the database*, eliminating the need to reload the application. Note, since you didn't post that function, I don't know what you're actually calling `addMe` - make sure to adjust the name accordingly.

Comment: Can you give me more details about how addme works. thank you